# Order stores by opening time in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table in my mySQL database looks like below:

```
id | shop_id | day | open | close
---------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1   | 8    | 18
---------------------------------
2  | 100     | 2   | 9    | 17
---------------------------------
3  | 200     | 1   | 8    | 16
---------------------------------
4  | 220     | 4   | 10   | 17
```

and so on where `day` is `int` between 1-7 and I want to make aa `SELECT` which order my results by current opened shop based on current time. This query will be paginated so idea to select all rows and order it in PHP isn't correct way. Is there a way to query like this:

Current time is 15:00 and the query should return order like 1, 3, 2, 4 or if time is 17:00 then 1,2,4,3. First get today's opened shops, then tomorrow, and so on...

Comment: really bad approach to store the data

Comment: i think this question -as it is now- belongs to peoples per hour.com

Comment: @Zeljka in what schema should I reconfigure the table to make it a "good approach" in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lpad()` and `concat()` to make comparable times for the columns `open` and `close` and then sort like this:

```
set @time1 = '15:00';
select * 
from tablename
order by 
  @time1 not between concat(lpad(open, 2, '0'), ':00') and concat(lpad(close, 2, '0'), ':00'),
  lpad(open, 2, '0'),
  id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ba26bad9dbeb5a0c463ca63a2dde786e).

Comment: Thanks @forpas. Looks like this is what I'm looking for